The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":0,"routes":[{"name":"Home"}]} was not handled by any navigator
I am stuck with an error. When I am trying to reset the screen navigation stack, I am getting this:
ERROR  The action 'RESET' with payload {"index":0,"routes":\[{"name":"Home"}\]} was not handled by any navigator.
This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.
This is my code
App.tsx
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Providers
import AppProvider from "./src/Context/Provider";
import AuthProvider, { useAuth } from "./src/Context/AuthContext";

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthenticatedStack from "./src/Navigation/AuthenticatedStack";
import UnauthenticatedStack from "./src/Navigation/UnauthenticatedStack";

// App Navigator
const AppNavigator = () => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAuth();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log('====================================');
  console.log('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);
  console.log('====================================');

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return isLoggedIn ? <AuthenticatedStack /> : <UnauthenticatedStack />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <AppNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});


AuthenticatedStack:
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from '../Screens/HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from '../Screens/ProfileScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthenticatedStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthenticatedStack;

UnauthenticatedStack:
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignupScreen from '../Screens/SignupScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../Screens/LoginScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const UnauthenticatedStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default UnauthenticatedStack;


Logout Function:
const handleLogout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
    AsyncStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
    navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ name: "Login" }],
    })
  };

Login Function:
const handleLogin = ()=>{
await AsyncStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(true));
        navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [{ name: "Home" }],
        });
}

I think when I am not logged screen the state on isLoggedIn is false and it loads the UnauthenticatedStack. Then when the state of the isLoggedIn changes to true after logging in, the AuthenticatedStack does not load and it shows error that Home is not recognized as the route.
When I reload the app, the AuthenticatedStack loads and the Home screen is shown. This also happens when I log out from the profile screen.
Can someone tell me the solution? I have browsed the whole internet and read the documentation but can not find the solution to this.
I want it so that if I log in to the app it redirects to the home screen, and when I log out then it redirects to the login screen
